# Android: java.lang.RuntimeException: at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

I created an application on live street view which is perfectly working on Lollipop and above but crashes on android 4.4 and below. on the crashes i got this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 

at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:4797)


 at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:4389)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4329)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1256)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5021)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:785)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:601)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you found an answer elsewhere

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have uninstalled the app and It worked.